# pd.pivot_table introduces NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, nan

I'm new to python and I was hoping to get some help here.

I want to convert my data from long to wide format with `pd.pivot_table`.

My data looks like this:

```
  TimeStamp [us] Source Channel Label Value [pV] Spike
0              1                   A1          0     0
1              2                   A1      -1400     1
2              3                   A1          0     0
3              1                   B1      -1400     1
4              2                   B1          0     0
5              3                   B1          0     0
```

and i want it like this

```
TimeStamp [us]          1    2    3
Source Channel Label               
A1                    0.0  1.0  0.0
B1                    1.0  0.0  0.0
```

[here some code to reproduce:]

```
#read in example
example_1 = {'TimeStamp [us]': ["1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3",],
            'Source Channel Label': ["A1", "A1", "A1","B1", "B1", "B1"],
            'Value [pV]': ["0", "-1400", "0","-1400", "0", "0"],
            'Spike': ["0", "1", "0", "1","0", "0"]}

#convert to dataframe
example_1 = pd.DataFrame(example_1)

#convert to wide format - works 
example_wide = pd.pivot_table(example_1, index='Source Channel Label', columns = 'TimeStamp [us]',values = 'Spike') #Reshape from long to wide

print(example_wide)
```

In this example it works fine. However, when I use this code on my real data (see example below), many NaN's are introduced. Any ideas why and most importantly, how to solve it?

```
       TimeStamp [µs] Source Channel Label  Value [pV]  Spike
0              402600                  F10           0    0.0
1              402700                  F10           0    0.0
2              402800                  F10           0    0.0
3              402900                  F10           0    0.0
4              403000                  F10     -149012    1.0
              ...                  ...         ...    ...
845142      299700800                  G10           0    0.0
845143      299700900                  G10           0    0.0
845144      299701000                  G10           0    0.0
845145      299701100                  G10           0    0.0
845146      299701200                  G10           0    0.0

[825902 rows x 4 columns]
```

convert to wide: `week6_233C_1_wide = pd.pivot_table(week6_233C_1, index='Source Channel Label', columns = 'TimeStamp [µs]',values = 'Spike') #Reshape from long to wide`

```
TimeStamp [µs]        1000  10000  100000  ...  99999300  99999400  99999500
Source Channel Label                       ...                              
A1                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
A10                    NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0
A2                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
A3                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
A4                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
                   ...    ...     ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
M5                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
M6                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
M7                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
M8                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
M9                     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN

[114 rows x 528921 columns]
```

Comment: A pivot is a representation of all combinations. If you have all values for each (index, columns), you will not have null values (like your example). If you have sparse data (like your real case), you will introduce null values.

Comment: You have NaNs because not all combinations of row/column existed in the long form. Use `fill_value=0` to fill them